# Significato di "impiantito" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning

Nella commedia *Sotto paga! Non si paga!* di Dario Fo (testo aggiornato nel 2007 e pubblicato da Einaudi) ho letto:

> Dei morti nelle officine e nei cantieri
>   non ne parlano mai! Ma sai quanti sono in Italia, secondo l’ultima inchiesta della CEE, i morti sul lavoro? Gli
>   operai che cadono dagli **impiantiti** senza protezione?
>   Quelli schiacciati dalle gru e dai bulldozer?

Ho letto tutte le accezioni di "impiantito" che appaiono sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI07/00000474.jpg). Tuttavia, non riesco a capire del tutto bene il significato di questo termine nel brano sopra citato. Da dove cadono questi operai che lavorano senza protezione? Dal pavimento dei palazzi che stanno costruendo? Dal soffitto o dal tetto di questi palazzi?

Comment: Secondo me voleva dire *impalcature* e gli è sfuggito *impiantiti*.

Comment: Credo si riferisca ai pavimenti, o meglio ai pavimenti mentre sono in costruzione, con un leggero slittamento di significato.

Comment: Non escludo che sia un refuso e la parola corretta fosse *impianti*.

Comment: Grazie, @neclepsio, ma si dice "cadere dagli impianti"?

Comment: Sì @charo: si parla di morti sul lavoro. In questo caso "impianto (industriale)" può riferirsi a praticamente qualsiasi struttura produttiva di un'industria.

Comment: Azzardo un'ipotesi, imparentata con quella di @Benedetta: mentre il significato odierno è più o meno un sinonimo di “pavimentazione”, guardando qua e là tra le occorrenze della parola in testi d'epoca su Google Books, sembra che in alcuni casi fosse usato per indicare ripiani orizzontali di qualche tipo, come soppalchi, piattaforme e simili. Se è giusto quello che capisco, può facilmente riferisci ai solai in costruzione o addirittura ai ripiani delle impalcature.

Comment: Concordo con @DaG ed aggiungo che, probabilmente, Fo si riferisce alle passerelle industriali tipo [questa](https://www.mazzacani.it/files/acatalogV/product/passerella_serbatoi_1.jpg) o [questa](http://www.lucchinivittore.it/public/realizzazioni/138.jpg)

Comment: Aggiungo che l'edilizia (e ferramenta) hanno un vocabolario particolare tutto loro che può variare molto da regione a regione, può darsi che a Milano si usi 'impiantito' per dire 'impalcatura'. Il linguaggio dei cantieri è molto particolare, ad esempio, avete mai sentito 'giapponetto' o 'vergale'? Sono termini locali, a Napoli, anche se 'giapponetto' è italiano.

Answer (score 0):

Nessuno cade dagli impiantiti, non ha alcun senso.

Per qualche strano motivo, Fo ha scritto *impiantiti* invece di *impalcature* dalle quali, purtroppo, gli operai cadono ancor oggi.

Può darsi che Fo voglia mettere in bocca uno strafalcione al personaggio che pronuncia la frase, ma è più probabile un suo strafalcione, visto che Il GDLI esclude altre letture: impiantito nel senso di una delle piattaforme delle impalcature è davvero molto stiracchiato.

Di seguito la voce sul GDLI

[image]

[image]

Comment: Giusto, nella voce “impiantito” non c'è niente che faccia pensare a piattaforme o simili, ma già guardando tutte le occorrenze della parola nel GDLI in generale, qualcosa di promettente c'è. Per esempio, a p. 1037, alla voce “Inghiozzare (2)”, leggiamo: “Al  nome  di  Viareggio,  ch’egli,  ripeten­dolo  infuriato,  inghiozzò  con  accento  sull’ò,  balzando sull’impiantito  di  tavole  che  gli  fece  da  pedana,  saltò un mezzo metro per aria e uscì in una sfuriata di parole”. Se è una cosa su cui si può balzare, forse se ne può anche cadere.

Comment: @DaG Mi pare molto stiracchiato. Non è detto che un premio Nobel sia esente dalle cantonate e questa mi pare proprio una. A meno che il contesto non chiarisca, come ho scritto.

Comment: @egreg, perché pare stiracchiato? Stabilito che impiantito sia sinonimo di pavimento, non mi pare che nella definizione ci sia alcunché che escluda che tale pavimento possa essere sospeso, come quello di un balcone, o sopraelevato, come quello di una pedana. Con questo non voglio dire che Fo non possa aver usato il termine in modo improprio o comunque oscuro ma solo che nell'ambito della domanda posta da Charo, ossia cosa intendesse Fo e da dove cadano gli operai a cui si fa riferimento, la risposta di DaG sia corretta.

Comment: @secan Con il plurale il senso è ovviamente generico. Un impiantito particolare può essere fatto di tavole su cui si può rimbalzare, non in generale. Fino a qualche anno (o decennio?) fa, le impalcature attorno alle case per costruzioni o manutenzioni avevano assi di legno per camminarci sopra. Ma da questo a chiamarle “impiantiti” ce ne corre.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @secan, è chiaro cosa intende Fo, e può darsi che ci sia un uso regionale di 'impiantito' per 'impalcatura' nei cantieri. Ma comunque, essendo Fo un premio Nobel per la letteratura, escluderei lo strafalcione, o almeno un premio Nobel è autorizzatoi a usare il linguaggio in modo personale. Diciamo che è lui che fa scuola, non è lui che deve accodarsi pedissequamente alle convenzioni.